# SQL select Distinct with where clause

Tags: sql

I have i table like this.

```
PersonID, KvalifikationId
1         1
1         2
1         3
2         1
2         3
```

I want to write SQL querye returning all persons, that have not kvalifikation 2.

i Wrote

```
SELECT DISTINCT PersonID where NOT KvalifikationID = 2
```

But this return both person 1 and person 2.
How do i make select that only return personId's that not have kval2 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT DISTINCT PersonID
FROM tableName
WHERE PersonID NOT IN
    (
        SELECT PersonID
        FROM tableName
        WHERE KvalifikationId = 2
    )
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5c8b/17)

Comment: In this case this probably works, because PersonID is presumably unique.  But if the column you are trying to get the distinct values for is not unique, then you could easily eliminate some values because there happened to be one in the set of rows you excluded.

Answer (score 4):

```
Declare @t table(PersonID int,KvalifikationId int)
Insert Into @t Select 1 ,1
Insert Into @t Select 1, 2
Insert Into @t Select 1,3
Insert Into @t Select 2 ,1
Insert Into @t Select 2,3

Select PersonId From @t

Except 

Select PersonID From @t where KvalifikationId = 2
```

**Result**

```
PersonId
2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT person_id
FROM tableName t1
WHERE not exists 
(
  select 1 
  from tableName 
  where person_id = t1.person_id and KvalifikationId = 2 
)
```

Answer (score 3):

By using your `Person` table rather than your N:N table in the outer query you can skip the `distinct` and the anti semi join to the sub query will have better performance since it is on  a clustered index. (assuming `PersonID` is pk in the `Person` table)

```
SELECT PersonID
FROM tblPerson
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM tblPersonKvalifikation
        WHERE KvalifikationId = 2 AND 
              tblPerson.PersonID = tblPersonKvalifikation.PersonID
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

try this.
SELECT DISTINCT PersonID from tableName
WHERE KvalifikationId NOT IN ('2');